# I'm trying to delete an entry by using a checkbox from my psql database using jsp and servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I'm trying to delete a checked entry from my database but it's not working.

The jsp page code is as follows:

```
    <c:forEach var="raportti" items="${raportit}"> 
        <tr value="${raportti.raportti_id}" >
         <td><c:out value="${raportti.potilasraportti}"/></td>
         <td ><c:out value="${raportti.hoito_ohjeet}"/></td>
         <td>  
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="${raportti.raportti_id}"/></td>
        </tr> </c:forEach>
```

The servlet looks like this:

```
else if (button.equals("Poista")&&request.getParameter("asiakas") 
!=null&& request.getParameter("checkbox") !=null) {
           List<Raportti> raportit=(List<Raportti>)request.getAttribute("checkbox");

            checkbox = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("checkbox"));
          //  raportti_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("raportti"));
            try {
                Raportti r = new Raportti();
                r.poistaRaportti(checkbox);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Laakarinsivu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NamingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Laakarinsivu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

The method in my class is this:

```
 public void poistaRaportti(int raportti_id) throws SQLException, NamingException {

    String sql = "DELETE FROM raportti WHERE raportti_id = ?";
    Connection yhteys = Yhteys.getYhteys();
    PreparedStatement kysely = yhteys.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet tulokset = kysely.executeQuery();
    kysely.close();

    tulokset.close();

    yhteys.close();
}
```

I'm trying to get the "raportti_id" value out by clicking the checkbox but it's not deleting once I press the delete button. Any suggestions?

Comment: The List in the servlet doesn't do anything I just forgot to remove it. I was trying so many different things to get it to work and that was one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parameter id and use `executeUpdate` for the database write operation:

```
kysely.setInt(1, raportti_id);
int rows = kysely.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: What is the int rows part?

Comment: rows = rows affected, i.e. no resultset for a DB update

Comment: Do I have to do anything else with it? It's just saying it's never used

Comment: You don't _have_ to use it but its useful to see the number of rows deleted

Comment: It's still not deleting :/ Am I getting the id from the checkbox right?

Comment: Looks ok, print out the value you get for `request.getParameter("checkbox")`

Comment: It works! The problem was in the method I called the other elements in the table from. The id was coming through as 0 for each entry. Thank you for your help